# iOS UITableView with UIPickerView

Tags: ipad, ios5, uitableview, uipickerview

I need to create a `UITableView` with multiple columns. In that, there will be a constant block on the top row of the table. When the user scrolls through the table, the row which is there in that block, will be picked. Basically it is a table view with `UIPickerView`.

I wish I was able to upload an image to explain this.

I'm not sure how to go about this. This is a hybrid of `UITableView` and picker view. Can I implement this is as a picker view of course with multi column (the block acting as a custom picker)?

Please help.

Thanks,
~Vishal

Answer (score 0):

YOu can get an index to the data represented in your top row using the UITableView method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

where point would be (CGPoint){0,0} (or some point which intersects with your block/row 1)

or

```
 - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowsInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

where rect would relate to you "block".

you will want to manage the scrolling so that the table comes to rest with the top of a row aligned with the block or top of the table. This UITableView method may prove helpful, you should trigger it when your tableview comes to rest after a scroll:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
              atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition 
                      animated:(BOOL)animated
```

with `UITableViewScrollPositionTop` as the scroll position

I expect you want each column to scroll independently. In that case you would need one tableView per column. Then you just need to make sure you know which tableView is doing the message sending in your respective delegate and datasource methods (easy to manage as a pointer to the tableView is the first parameter sent in those methods).